# Combining two MySQL queries into a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that takes a CSV file and uploads it into a MySQL table. Each of the entries upon the upload features characters that I need to remove, as well as the head row. For example:

```
`| ="username" | ="URL" |`
`| ="john"  | ="url"   |`
`| ="mike"  | ="url1"  |`
```

At the moment, I use the following two queries via phpMyAdmin to update the entries and delete the first row:

`update control set userName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(userName,'"',''), '"',''), '=','');`

`DELETE FROM control WHERE userName = "Username"`

Is there a way to combine the two queries into a single one with the goal of running the resulting query with a button click through PHP script?

Comment: You cannot combine two different sql statements into one, but you can run the two sql statements one after the other in a single transaction with a button click through php.

Comment: PHP can execute as many queries in one script as you wish. There's no need to combine them...just execute them one after another in the same PHP script.

Comment: Why do you need to _remove_ the header row _after_ the import, why was that not excluded _during_ the import already?

Comment: Is this a one time process or something you do multiple times? If multiple times I would fix the data prior to importing

Comment: @user3783243 I am doing it regularly, as the main table is truncated and filled with new data.

Comment: Is the above a real example of your file? Can you add how you currently are doing the insert for this? The inserting should be fixed, then you won't need to do this fixing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine a `DELETE` query with an `UPDATE` query unfortunately.

What you can do however is combine the queries inside a transaction so that they are run consecutively and are rolled back if anything goes wrong.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE control SET userName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(userName,'"',''), '"',''), '=','');
DELETE FROM control WHERE userName = "Username"
COMMIT;
```

In terms of PHP this could look something like the following:

```
$pdo = new PDO('some dsn string');
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->exec("UPDATE control SET userName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(userName,'"',''), '"',''), '=','')");
$pdo->exec("DELETE FROM control WHERE userName = "Username"");
$pdo->commit();
```

Above is using the PHP PDO library as an example.

[MySQL Transaction Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)

[PHP PDO Transaction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)